# Cannot set property '3' of undefined

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I am getting this error to create an object with this code.

```
let i = 0;
adminItems.forEach(adminItem => {
    this.coinmarketService.getDataByName(adminItem.coinname)
    .subscribe(response => {
        let coinItem = response.json();
        this.items[i] = {
            'name': coinItem[0].name,
            'symbol': coinItem[0].symbol,
            'price_usd': coinItem[0].price_usd,
            'price_btc': coinItem[0].price_btc,
            'percent_change_24h_usd': coinItem[0].percent_change_24h,
            'percent_change_24h_btc': coinItem[0].percent_change_24h,
            'percent_btc': ((1 / coinItem[0].price_btc) * 100),
            'percent_potential': adminItem.percentage,
            'description': adminItem.description
        };
        console.log(this.items);
    });
    i++;
});
```

And here is the detail error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property '3' of undefined
>       at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (dashboard.component.ts:32)
>       at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:239)
>       at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:186)
>       at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:127)
>       at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:91)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.es5.js:1226)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)

Comment: Can you show us your **full source code**?

Comment: Either your problem is that your `items` variable isn't an array but an object, or you're not showing your whole code (thus, nor your error).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here is the full source code. Please check it and let me know what you think. https://plnkr.co/edit/c8msU8k4xQ4jEmcjfxD3?p=preview

Comment: The code is not so clear. i suggest 2 things. 1- try to log coinItem right after you do `let coinItem = response.json();` at line 33 . 2- `try to do items: DashboardItem[] = [];` at line 17 . otherwise check your `coinmarketService`.

Comment: coinItem and others don't have any problem. It's only this.items[i] = {
                                        'name': coinItem[0].name,
                                        'symbol': coinItem[0].symbol,
                                        'price_usd': coinItem[0].price_usd,
                                        'price_btc': coinItem[0].price_btc,
                                        'percent_change_24h_usd': coinItem[0].percent_change_24h,
                                        'percent_change_24h_btc': coinItem[0].percent_change_24h, ...}

Comment: The this.items[i] = {...} part

Comment: How about show the code via teamviewer?